# movie about a baby that drinks blood

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw this movie about 5 years ago on either HBO or Showtime. I believe it is an American movie.  A woman is pregnant and she and her husband get in a car accident. The man dies but the wife survives and is told her child is dead and will be stillborn.  The child is delivered, is alive, but only wants blood to drink. The only other thing I remember is the child breastfeeding and there being a lot of blood from it. Sorry, that is all I remember.

Comment: This sounds like The Notebook (2004).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like [Grace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_%28film%29) from 2009, which was [based on a short film](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0831365/combined).

> Michael Matheson (Stephen Park) and his pregnant wife Madeline (Jordan Ladd) are involved in a car accident. Michael dies, and doctors tell Madeline that her unborn child is dead, too. Madeline, desperate after trying to have a child for years, decides to carry her baby to term anyway. The child, a girl, initially appears stillborn. After a while, though, she seems to revive, and Madeline names her "Grace". It soon becomes clear something is wrong with the baby. It develops unhealthy smells, attracts flies, and craves blood.

Here's the trailer (**Warning: A bit graphic**):